# Преобразование временного формата

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как убрать ноль в начале строки во втором ассерте?

```
def time_converter(time):
        #replace this for solution
        time=time.split(':')
        for i,item in enumerate(time):
            time[i]=int(item)
        #z=list(time[0]) 
       # for i,item in enumerate(z):
          #  z[i]=int(item)
        if time[0]>12:
            time[0]-=12
            return str(time[0])+':'+str(time[1])+' p.m.' 
        elif time[0]==12:
            return str(time[0])+':'+str(time[1])+' p.m.' 
        elif time[0]<12:
            return str(time[0])+':'+str(time[1])+' a.m.'
        elif z[0]==0:

            return str(z[1])+':'+str(time[1])+' a.m.'


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Example:")
        print(time_converter('12:30'))

        #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
        assert time_converter('12:30') == '12:30 p.m.'
        assert time_converter('09:00') == '9:00 a.m.'
        assert time_converter('23:15') == '11:15 p.m.'
```

Вы предпочитаете использовать 12-часовой формат времени, но современный мир живет в 24-часовом формате и вывидите это повсюду. Ваша задача - переконвертировать время из 24-часового формата в 12-часовой, использкя следующие правила:
- выходной формат должен быть 'чч:мм a.m.' (для часов до полудня) или 'чч:мм p.m.' (для часов после полудня)
- если часы меньше 10 - не пишите '0' перед ними. Например: '9:05 a.m.'
Как убрать ноль в начале строки во втором ассерте?

Comment: можно `lstrip(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогичное соседнему [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1034949/201445), но через `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_converter(t: str):
    return datetime\
        .strptime(t, '%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')\
        .lstrip('0').lower().replace('m', '.m.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(time_converter('12:30'))

    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert time_converter('12:30') == '12:30 p.m.'
    assert time_converter('09:00') == '9:00 a.m.'
    assert time_converter('23:15') == '11:15 p.m.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно ли использовать класс [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.time), функцию [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html?highlight=strptime#time.strptime) и [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html?highlight=strftime#time.strftime)? Если да, то:

```py
from time import strptime
from datetime import time
time_converter = lambda t: time(*strptime(t, '%H:%M')[3:5]).strftime('%I:%M %p').lstrip('0').lower().replace('m', '.m.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(time_converter('12:30'))

    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert time_converter('12:30') == '12:30 p.m.'
    assert time_converter('09:00') == '9:00 a.m.'
    assert time_converter('23:15') == '11:15 p.m.'
```

Демо на [Rextester](https://rextester.com/ERAOD87576).